# Attach a different camera to host while it is running

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

In cwac-camera, I can override useFrontFacingCamera() to get either of the cameras on my device.

```
@Override public boolean useFrontFacingCamera() {
}
```

This is working fine, as long as I configure it before the host is built. But once the host is built and the preview is started, the event is not raised anymore and the camera therefore does not change.

What is the correct way to switch the camera while the preview is running?

I have tried to use restartPreview() which does not work because the preview is not actually stopped when restartPreview() is called. I cannot call stopPreview() because it is private. I saw there is a PreviewStrategy interface which might be there to cater for this functionality, but it's not documented and I don't understand how it's used. Sure I could tear everything down and set it up from scratch, but I guess that's not the way it should be done.

Can anybody shed light please.

PS: This is not a complaint about the documentation of the library. Not many other libraries are documented so thoroughly. It's just missing and/or I am to stupid to use it ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to switch the camera while the preview is running?

Switch to a separate `CameraFragment`, as the demo app does. There is no means to switch the camera once the fragment is created.

Comment: I am not using fragments, but used the view directly. So destroying and recreating the view would be the correct way? Would you rather destroy and re-create the same view, or would it be more efficient to keep two separate views and switch them?

Comment: @OliverHausler: "Would you rather destroy and re-create the same view, or would it be more efficient to keep two separate views and switch them?" -- keeping two views and switching them should work, as that's effectively what's going on with the fragments. So long as you call `onPause()` on the `CameraView` you're (temporarily) not using, it will `release()` its camera. Just be sure to call `onResume()` on it as you start to use it again.

Comment: thank you very much. I think that is a very nice solution, because it allows to keep all the settings per camera and just switch them back and forth.